# Need to receive an error

Tags: php

Since I'm starting to get mysql to mysqli I've a some problems.

I've a page for exampe `category.php?nameID=premium&id=12` This is a valid page with information, so when I go to for example: `category.php?nameID=premium&id=1200` This page doesn't exist so I need to receive an error with `This page doesn\'t exists!`

```
$naamID = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_GET['nameID']));
$id     = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_GET['id']));
$idnext = $id + 1;
$goo    = $db->query("SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN post ON category.name = post.cat WHERE post.cat = '" .$naamID. "' AND post.id = $id") or die($db->error);
//$gnn    = $db->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id= $id ") or die(mysql_error());
//$gnnn     = $gnn->fetch_assoc;
if($gooo = $goo->fetch_object()); 
if ($gooo === FALSE) 
{
echo '<p>This post doesnot exist!</p>';
}
```

Comment: Try using `if((int)$gooo->id==0)` or something you are sure isn't 0

Comment: Working! searched almost 2 hours for this, learning every day things here on stackoverflow! Thank you could you please Answer as question so I can mark it

Comment: Mark the other answer it works too :) and put a space between `does` and `not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `num_rows` to count rows in your query. If it is 0, there are no results and post does not exist.

```
if($goo->num_rows==0){
  echo '<p>This post does not exist!</p>';
} else {
  if($gooo = $goo->fetch_object()){
    //exists
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom 404 error page then try this [404](http://cs-fundamentals.com/web-development/create-custom-404-page-not-found-error-page.php).